# Listing tar contents inside directory

Tags: linux, bash

this is the script I'm running

```
tar tf some.tar somefolder_insidetar
```

And output it's a list with all folders, files, and SUBDIRECTORY Files, the only thing I need it's just show the contents (folder and files) of the current directory choosed, not listing subdirectory files, or subdirectories inside subdirectories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
tar tf some.tar somefolder_insidetar | grep "somefolder_insidetar/[^/]*/\?$"
```

Comment: Didn't work, Just makes a list of every the whole tar

Comment: I just edited it...please try this again

Comment: Well this one doesn't show anything

Comment: sorry, missed a slash :p I'll copy-n-paste this time...

Comment: Yes this works, Thank you very much! really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check this post, looks similar to what you are asking
[Listing the content of a tar file or a directory only down to some level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700306/listing-the-content-of-a-tar-file-or-a-directory-only-down-to-some-level)

Comment: That's not what im searching, already tried

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude the subdirectories with `grep -v`:

```
tar  tvzf ../xrick-021212.tgz xrick-021212 | grep -v 'xrick-021212/.*/'
```

Comment: What i want to exclude are FILES inside subdirectories, just show current folder files & directories

Comment: @Jesus: then add a dot at the end, to prevent the exclusion of subdirectories.